# Is there a way to prevent users from doing bulk entries in a Postgresql Database

Tags: database, postgresql, access-control

I have 4 new data entry users who are using a particular GUI to create/update/delete entries in our main database. The "GUI" client allows them to see database records on a map and make modifications there, which is fine and preferred way of doing it.

But lately lot of guys have been accessing local database directly using PGAdmin and running bulk queries (i.e. update, insert, delete,etc) which introduces lot of problems like people updating lot of records without knowing or making mistakes while setting values. It also effects our logging procedures as we are calculating averages and time stamps for reporting purposes which are quite crucial to us.

So is there a way to prevent users from using PGAdmin (please remember lot of these guys are working from home and we do not have access to their machines) and running SQL queries directly in the database.

We still have to give them access to certain tables and allow them to execute sql as long as it's coming through a certain client but deny access to same user when he/she tries to execute a query directly in the db.

Answer (score 1):

The only sane way to control access to your database is converting your db access methods to 3-tier structure. You should build a middleware (maybe some rest API or something alike) and use this API from your app. Database should be hidden behind this middleware, so no direct access is possible. From DB point of view, there are no ways to tell if one database connection is from your app, or from some other tool (pgadmin, simple psql or some custom build client). Your database should be accessible only from trusted hosts and clients should not have access to those hosts.

Comment: Adding middleware layer is unnecessary complexity for a very simple application that he describes. Simply controling the access through granting access to specific server side methods is more than enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you use a trick (which might get exploited, too, but maybe your users are not smart enought).

In your client app set some harmless parameter like geqo_pool_size=1001 (if it is 1000 normally).

Now write a trigger that checks if this parameter is set and outputs "No access through PGAdmin" if this parameter is not set like from your app (and the username is not your admin username).

Alternatives: Create a temporary table and check for its existance.

Comment: It is a solution in the spirit of 'security through obscurity' which is strictly discouraged in production environment.

Comment: If his contraints are that the users MUST know her PG credentials, how would you do it? Without middleware?

Comment: IMHO, if someone wants to shoot himself in a leg, you shouldn't suggest him a better way to do that. You should explain him how bad that idea is. Direct database connection is a bad idea in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should block direct access to the database, and set an application to which your clients (humans and software ones) will be able to connect.

Let this application filter and pass only allowed commands.

A great care should be taken in the filtering - I would carefully think whether raw SQL would be allowed at all. Personally, I would design some simplified API, which would make me sure that a hypothetical client-attacker (*In God we trust, all others we monitor*) would not find a way to sneak with some dangerous modification.

I suppose that from security standpoint your current approach is very unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You should study advanced `pg_hba.conf` [settings](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

this file is the key point for use authorization. Basic settings imply only simple authentification methods like passwords and lists of IP, but you can have some more advanced solution.

- GSSAPI
- kerberos
- SSPI
- Radius server
- any pam method

So your official client can use a more advanced method, like somthing with a third tier API, some really complex authentification mechanism. Then without using the application it will at least becomes difficult to redo these tasks. If the kerberos key is encrypted in your client, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to REVOKE your users write access, then create a new role with write access, then as this role you CREATE FUNCTION defined as SECURITY DEFINER, which updates the table in a way you allow with integrity checks, then GRANT EXECUTE access to this function for your users.

There is an answer on this topic on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/67201/postgresql-permission-to-execute-function-that-inserts-into-a-table-but-no-per) which references the following [blog entry](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/08/18/securing-your-postgresql-database/) with detailed description.

I believe that using middleware as other answers suggest is an unnecessary overkill in your situation. The above solution does not require for the users to change the way they access the database, just restricts their right to modify the data only through the predefined server side methods.